# Azure Integration Account - How to manage nested / composed schemas

Tags: azure, xsd, schema, azure-logic-apps

I have 2 xsd files example `parent.xsd` and `child.xsd`

With in child.xsd, I do have reference to parent.xsd as show below

Now in my logic app I want to use child.xsd which further has refernce to parent.xsd

In the integration account I have uploaded child.xsd and parent.xsd files as schema artifacts but how the child.xsd will come to know it has refer to the parent.xsd within the same integration account.

or

for parent.xsd do I need to store it in blob container and in use its URI in the child.xsd schemaLocation ?

e.g :

`<xs:include schemasLocation = "http://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/myconatiner/parent.xsd"/>`

Please suggest the right way of doing it.

Comment: If you upload `parent.xsd` to integration account, the schema location should be `schemaLocation="xml.xsd"`

Answer (score 0):

When we upload schema files to an integration account schema artifacts section then all uploaded files resides within same directory/location in Azure.

In schema file **schemaLocation="ABC.xsd"** will be suffice to refer to another xsd files in the integration account schemas artifacts.